# Visual Studio 2019 keeps asking to re-enter credentials for Azure DevOps

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2019, azure-devops

I am using the below version of Visual Studio, and I have logged in with my Azure DevOps Credentials. However, again and again, Visual Studio says "We need to refresh the credentials for this account. Re-enter your credentials". Please refer to the screenshot for reference. I have tried removing the account and adding it again. It stays there for some time and then it is asking again. Any suggestions on how to fix this would be very helpful.

```
Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019 (2)
Version 16.10.2
```

[Visual Studio 2019 Account Settings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2DC7F.png)

Comment: It's normal for Visual Studio 2019 to ask for you to reauthenticate your user account after awhile.  The fact you removed the account and were still unable to refresh your credentials indicates Visual Studio is unable to access the internet.  I have no aware of any method to use Visual Studio 2019 Community offline.

Comment: No, I am having an active internet connection. It is getting refreshed however every 2 minutes or so it is prompting to enter the credentials again and again.

Comment: I'm having the same issue with 16.10.4 it keeps prompting every couple of minutes for login while I am already logged in.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Try this:

> in order to reduce the reauthentication, you can try to enable “System
> web browser” under Tools > Options > Environment > Accounts > Add and
> reauthenticate accounts using: dropdown. Then, sign in your accounts
> again.

More info [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/visualstudio/ide/work-with-multi-factor-authentication?view=vs-2019)

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem when opening a solution from a client. Their projects relied on Nugets from their Azure DevOps repo and everytime Visual Studio would try to restore those packages during build I'd be hit with the login popup forever. I *had* access to their DevOps, I could log in and read and edit bug reports and everything looked great, except VS2022 wouldn't have it.

I tried all sorts of account logout/login in VS2022, I switched to the system web browser and whatnot, but nothing helped. Until finally: In the VS build output the Nuget restore would complain about that remote package config, providing me with the exact .json URL. Following *that* link took me to a slightly different DevOps login, with more error messages. From there I logged out (again) and logged in again, which this time required the customer's 2-way authentication. After that, VS 2022 stopped asking and everything worked fine.

Apparently **you can be logged in to DevOps in multiple ways at the same time**, using the same account, and some login can remain while you log out everywhere else. The Visual Studio login prompt apparently can target the "wrong" login. Azure DevOps is a mess.

Answer (score 0):

in this case you can do one more thing you can just remove you laptop credential if you are using windows thank go credential manager and after that go to windows credential  and clear visual studio credential may be it will work

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -2):

Stuck in the same loop.

I try to push or pull, VS asks for credentials, after submitting it just prompts it again 3 times, then I get the 'Failed to push to remote...' error with no logging in Output. I have reset everything related to credentials, account, remote connections, even reinstalled VS and tried every solution I could find online.

Pulling my hair out here.

Comment: I'd suggest that you delete this, SE sites don't work quite this way. If you have a problem of your own, you should post a new question. You can refer (link) to this question if you will. "Me too" -type answers [aren't acceptable](https://superuser.com/help/deleted-answers). Please see the Help section on [how to answer](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-answer) and [how to ask a good question](https://superuser.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: Thanks for the help I guess

Comment: Well I guess you're welcome :-D